# Dynamically adding dom elements using Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have reached a dead end in searching for a solution to my problem.
The problem is, i have an .xml File which contains data which that help in generating html page on the fly. The data looks like this.
`<?xml version="1.0"?><Controls><TextInput XmlNodeBoundTo="TEXTINPUT1" Name="TEXTINPUT1" Id="T1></TextInput><TextInput XmlNodeBoundTo="TEXTINPUT2" Name="TEXTINPUT2" Id="T2"></TextInput></Controls>`

Now My problem is for each control if `tagName` is "TextInput" then i had to add a input `<input/>` control in the html page. This i have implemented in basic javascript, but I want to implement using KO, since i am a newbie to KO I am not able understand that much.
So guys any tutorials which are similar to my problem would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make a template and then bind view model to data Pls refer to below psedo code

```
<tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'comissionTemplate', foreach: Comissions }"></tbody> <script type="text/html" id="comissionTemplate">
    <tr >
        <td><input type='text'  data-bind="value: "based on object passed to obseravable array set the value here"/></td>
</tr>

viewModel = {
Comissions: ko.observableArray([])}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

So you need to parse the xml and push the data inside commisions and then bind to script tag

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so do i have to define template for each control?? and one more thing there can be element in tables(nested), and also each controls can appear in any order